# Passing ng-click through to template

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've found a few answers relating to this question, but I'm getting (at best) an "unexpected token" error.

I'm attempting to build a library of directives around the bootstrap framework to make markup lighter and my job easier when using bootstrap with angular.  First up is a `glyph-button`:

```
angular.module('angular-bootstrap', [])
.directive('glyphBtn', function(){

// Allowed button sizes
var _allowedSizes = ['xs', 'sm', 'lg'],
    _defaultClass = "btn-primary";

return {
  restrict :'EA',
  transclude : true,
  replace : true,
  scope : {
    clickHandler : '&ngClick',
    glyph : '@',          // The glyph name, defined at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons
    size : '@',           // Size of the button, lg, sm, xs
    bsClass : '@',           // "Class" of button, default, primary, success, info, warning, danger, link
    isActiveFn : '&',        // The function which dictates the buttons "active state"
    spaces : '@'
  },
  compile : function(tElement, tAttrs){
    // Normalize to btn-primary
    if(!tAttrs.bsClass)
      tAttrs.bsClass = _defaultClass;

    // Default size is empty string
    if(!tAttrs.size)
      tAttrs.size = "";

    // Link function:
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.getSpaces = function(){
        if(parseInt(scope.spaces) > 0)
          return " "; // only one space allowed in HTML
      }
      scope.getBSClass = function(){
        return attrs.bsClass;
      }
      scope.getSize = function(){
        if(_allowedSizes.indexOf(attrs.size) == -1)
          return '';
        return "btn-" + attrs.size;
      }
    }
  },
  template : '<button type="button" class="btn {{getBSClass()}} {{getSize()}}" ng-transclude><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{glyph}}"></span>{{getSpaces()}}</button>'
}
})

/* Usage:
<button glyph-btn 
  glyph="align-center" 
  isActiveFn="doToggle()" 
  size="sm"
  type="primary">Some Text</button>
*/
```

I'd like to have the `ng-click` method attached to the directive node, i.e.

```
<button glyph-btn glyph="chevron-right" size="lg" spaces="1" ng-click="test()">Test Button</button>
```

But I can't seem to get the `ng-click` method to "pass through" to the ng-click of the button in the template.  The best I can get is it being called like 4 times on load, and at worst nothing happens.

Answers I've looked at:

- [SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488769/ng-click-doesnt-work-within-the-template-of-a-directive)
- [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613992/ng-click-attribute-on-angularjs-directive)
- [SO 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039983/angular-js-how-to-pass-ngclick-from-original-dom-to-directives-dom)

My controller:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.test = function(){
    console.log("test")
  }
})
```

It could be just late in the night, but for the life of me I can't figure out why adding an `ng-click="clickHandler()"` would throw the following error:

> Error: Syntax Error: Token 'clickHandler' is an unexpected token at column 8 of the expression [test() clickHandler()] starting at [clickHandler()].

Everything else works fine, but passing ngClick (and I'm sure later when I try `ngClass`) it doesn't want to play nice.

Angular 1.0.8

### Edit

When the error is thrown, the incomplete (unparsed) markup shown in the console is:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="test() _clickHandle()" class="btn {{getBSClass()}} {{getSize()}}" ng-transclude="" glyph-btn="" glyph="chevron-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{glyph}}"></span>{{getSpaces()}}</button>
```

Which you can see it's copying both the method I pass in through the attributes of the directive (`test()`), AND the scope method from the directive's `return` into the `ng-click` attribute:

```
return {
restrict :'EA',
transclude : true,
replace : true,
scope : {
  _clickHandle : '&ngClick',
  glyph : '@',          // The glyph name, defined at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons
  size : '@',           // Size of the button, lg, sm, xs
  bsClass : '@',           // "Class" of button, default, primary, success, info, warning, danger, link
  isActiveFn : '&',        // The function which dictates the buttons "active state"
  spaces : '@'
}
```

Adding the surrounding `<div>` works, but that's silly and can break things (CSS, etc).  What am I missing?

Comment: can you post plunker/fiddle demo with your problem?

Comment: I seem to be inept with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap button inside a div and your problem will go away

```
<div><button glyph-btn glyph="chevron-right" size="lg" spaces="1" ng-click="test()">Test Button</button></div>
```

Comment: That... actually works. But why?!  What if I don't want the added markup?  There's only one root node in the template, so why would nesting it make it work magically?